# MSTest - What is the difference between writing messages directly to StdOut and using TestContext?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, mstest

I'm trying to figure out a good way to log messages to the console / test explorer / pipeline execution logs when running my MSTest Test Project.

I've noticed that you can either write the output to the console using the usual suspect:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your text here");
```

But you can also do it from TestContext object, for example:

```
TestContext _testContext;
_testContext.WriteLine("TEST CONTEXT : This is a test message");
```

The achieved result ends up in the same place (in the various logs) and also within the `.trx` file, under the "StdOut" messages:

```
<UnitTestResult >
    <Output>
        <StdOut>                
            TestInitialize&#xD;
            Test Name : AssertIsTrue&#xD;
            TestCleanup&#xD;
            
            TestContext Messages:&#xD;
            TEST CONTEXT : This is a test message
        </StdOut>
    </Output>
</UnitTestResult>
```

So I'm wondering what is the best / more sustainable course of action to enable proper "logging" within the various tests ?

(OR maybe I'm doing it totally wrong, and there is a good way to do it using a Logger or equivalent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation of [`TestContext.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.writeline?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) (the method is abstract) will most likely call [`Trace.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline?view=net-8.0) to have then all their [`TraceListeners`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener?view=net-8.0) write, store, output, email or queue the string.

That the console output ends up in the trx is more of a convenience I suspect in case that the test runner itself fails catastrophically.

Tracing and diagnostic output should always be written by means of the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` or `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class or implementations that use the same. If output of these is needed on the console, register the [`ConsoleTraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener?view=net-8.0).

That might make it easier in test case scenario's to determine that `Console.WriteLine` come from the Subject Under Test, not your unit test code.
This is under the assumption that the testrunner doesn't pile everything in one bag anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will have a look at the Trace & Debug topics more in depth, I guess that will point me in the right direction.